# No bluetooth applet visible in ubuntu 12.10 with mate desktopk environment!!!

Tags: 12.10, bluetooth, applet, mate

i have installed ubuntu 12.10 recently and also installed mate desktop 1.6 .....my problem is when i plug-in my usb bluetooth device ..no bt manager or applet appears on my mate panels ( my bt device is working in unity environment )...
may be mate bluetooth manager is not installed or activated...

please help me solve this as i love the mate desktop because of my background as a windows user.

thanks

Comment: Look for the mate-bluetooth package in the package manager; was it installed?

Comment: I can't find that package. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install mate-bluetooth
```

I believe its part of the mate-desktop-environment-extra  meta package, which rarely gets mentioned in MATE installation howtos hence why its probabley not in your install.